# How to set start position of draggable div?

Tags: javascript, css, position, draggable

I have a draggable `div` that works fine as long as I don't alter its position via `top, right, …` CSS. My goal is to set the pre-drag position of the div toward the top-right of its window, which I accomplish with `top = 0, right = 0`; problem is, the `div` sticks to that position and [stretches](https://jsfiddle.net/fzr2y7x4/23/) when dragging.

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("myModal"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
  document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;} 
  else {elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;}

  function dragMouseDown(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;}
    
  function elementDrag(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - w.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - w.clientY;
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";}

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;}}
```

```css
#myModal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;}
#myModalheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div id="myModal">
  <div id="myModalheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p><p>this</p><p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

Any workarounds? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the element a width and height and you should be good.

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("myModal"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
  document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;} 
  else {elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;}

  function dragMouseDown(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;}
    
  function elementDrag(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - w.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - w.clientY;
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";}

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;}}
```

```css
#myModal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9; height: 200px; width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;}
#myModalheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div id="myModal">
  <div id="myModalheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p><p>this</p><p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use flex box to put the container to the right instead.

```
#parentContainer{
    display: flex; justify-content: flex-end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two more options for doing this:

1. Do not use `right:0;` at all and use `left:100%; width:max-content;` followed by `transform: translateX(-100%);` so it offsets based on the child and not the parent:
   (Changes were only made to the css file)

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("myModal"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
  document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;} 
  else {elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;}

  function dragMouseDown(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;}
    
  function elementDrag(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - w.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - w.clientY;
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";}

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;}}
```

```css
#myModal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;                   /**Important*/
    transform: translateX(-100%); /**Important: offsets based on the element's width and not its parent*/
    width:max-content;            /**Important: prevents element from shrinking*/
    top:0;
}
    
#myModalheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal">
  <div id="myModalheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p><p>this</p><p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

2. The second option is to calculate the offset to the right of the element during the first drag and setting `right:0;` to `right:auto;` after done dragging
   (changes only made to the javascript file)

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("myModal"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
  document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;} 
  else {elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;}

  function dragMouseDown(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;}
    
  function elementDrag(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - w.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - w.clientY;
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    //Check if a right offset exists (will only be true
    //during the first time you drag it)
    if(elmnt.style.right != null && elmnt.style.right != "auto"){
      //calculate right offset
      var offsetright = window.innerWidth-elmnt.offsetLeft-elmnt.offsetWidth;
      //add the offset to the right of the element
      elmnt.style.right = (offsetright +pos1) + "px";
    }
    //end of change
    
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";}

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
    elmnt.style.right = "auto";
  }}
```

```css
#myModal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;}
#myModalheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div id="myModal">
  <div id="myModalheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p><p>this</p><p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't comment on the rest of the code but simply adding the three *important* lines worked: `left: 100%;`, then `transform: translateX(-100%);` and then finally `width:max-content;` was all it took to fix the problem.